# Continue playing videoview after interruption

Tags: android, android-videoview

So my video starts from the OnCreate method and continues looping indefinately(which is what i want). The problem is when i exit the app and go back into it the videoview is just a blank square where the view would be. Same thing occurs when i open up the camera . It's annoying as i have to close, delete the process and start the app to view the video again. Is there a way for the video to continue where it left off or even restart the video all together?

```
        VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    String uriPath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyVideo.3gp");

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();
    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simply call the default video player available in your system. That would take care of your issue. Use below code snippet

String videourl="path to video";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videourl));

startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

Nvm fixed it. just put

```
   mVideoView.start();
```

in the OnPrepared method

```
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mVideoView.start(); 
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }
```